Синонимизировать метки [react-router] и [react-router-dom]
Предлагаю синонимизировать следующие метки (на усмотрение сообщества):

react-router (293 вопроса)
react-router-dom (169 вопроса)

Основная метка - react-router:

Библиотека называется react-router, а react-router-dom лишь ее часть и наименование для скачивания из npmjs.com

Субъективно - большинство вопросов имеют ввиду react-router-dom, подразумевая общую библиотеку React Router - было бы удобно объединить не концентрируя внимания на деталях, которые 99%-м не особо интересны и даже сбивают с толку (а может это разные библиотеки?...)
Объективно - в npm все же react-router-dom, который лишь часть общей библиотеки и используется для конкретного направления разработки, а так же есть react-router-native который не равен react-router-dom. Поэтому - предложение на синонимизацию на усмотрение сообщества, пока дополнены описания меток, чтобы всем заинтересованным было понятнее особенности их взаимоотношения.
Обсуждение вопроса на enSO  - в итоге не объединили

Тем не менее, на enSO это разные метки. Почему нам стоит их объединить?

субъективно - большинство вопросов имеют ввиду react-router-dom, подразумевая общую библиотеку React Router - было бы удобно объединить не концентрируя внимания на деталях, которые 99%-м не особо интересны и даже сбивают с толку (а может это разные библиотеки?...)

Но объективно - в npm все же react-router-dom, который лишь часть общей библиотеки и используется для конкретного направления разработки, а так же есть react-router-native который не равен react-router-dom. Поэтому - снимаю предложение на синонимизацию - дополнены описания меток и чтобы всем заинтересованным было понятнее особенности взаимоотношения меток.

Опишите, пожалуйста, это всё в тексте самого предложения, чтобы не собирать по комментам. Ненужные комменты потом удалим. А для принятия решения о синонимизации, я думаю, надо как минимум, чтобы участники по этим меткам сюда пришли и тоже высказались. Так как сейчас явно не тот случай, что всё предельно понятно и от синонимизации не будет хуже.
